# adding values before mysql extraction or after?

Tags: php, mysql

Say this is our sql statement

```
SELECT points, value
FROM table WHERE x = y
```

This returns something like this

```
points  |  color
  5         red
  11        red
  2         blue
  9         blue
```

I would now like to add the points of the color "red" and add the points of color "blue". And then update the table with the new points.

What is the best approach for this? or is this better solved in a mysql statement before extraction?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS points, value
FROM yourtable
WHERE x = y
GROUP BY value
```

If you need  to update the table you can store this result in a tempoary table and then either rename the tables or delete all rows from the original table and then copy them from the temporary table.